# PHP Symfony Redis session lock

Tags: php, symfony, session, redis

I am using `RedisSessionHandler` as a default session in my local Symfony application. As I understand the default `redis.session.locking_enabled` parameter should be false. Yet I am still getting the session lock on every page load.

For example if I load the same page in multiple tabs at once I have to wait for these pages to load in the same queue as I opened them. Session is used to get the logged in user details.

Symfony app is running on Docker in this case.

What I am missing here? How non blocking Redis session should work?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently that was the Chrome issue. It loads all the opened pages one by one. Tried Firefox and everything loaded at the same time.